# Assign 2 page layouts to System admin profile

Tags: page-layout, administration, record-type

Suppose if I have an Object A and it has two page layouts layout1 and layout2. Layout1 is used for App1 and Layout2 is used for App2. So is there a way to default the layout for system admin, like if system admin launches app1 then layout1 should be displayed and if he launches app2 then layout2 should be display by default. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

No, the page layout depends on the Record Type and the Profile. You might want to add your voice to this [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdpXwUAJ/set-page-layout-on-lightning-app-by-record-page-not-record-type).

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Lightning and the object you're on is *custom* ([standard objects not yet supported](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdiWiUAJ/dependent-page-layouts-data-rules-to-show-hide-or-make-fieldssections-reqd)), you can achieve this by not utilizing page layouts and instead leveraging [Dynamic Forms](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_overview.htm&type=5) on Lightning Record Pages.

Instead of letting the page layout dictate the fields, you'd do all this through the Lightning record page and then do the assignment through the existing functionality which allows you to assign based on record types *and application*.

[image]